# How do I update Google Play Services on Android Studio?

Tags: java

I have changed the dependencies and installed the necessary files needed. However, whenever I run my emulator, a message with pop up saying that I have to update my Google Play Services. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: [this](https://www.google.co.in) will help more than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings from file and update the Google Play services from the SDK manager:

[image]